# mysql_fetch_assoc returns duplicated rows... 

Tags: php, mysql, duplicates, rows

My fetch_assoc returns duplicated rows. It seems that it multiplies itself. I have 4 inputs in my table and it returns 16.

Here is my code.... Please help me. I think I got the looping wrong.

```
<?php
$tryshow =" SELECT c.customer_date, c.lastname, c.firstname,
   s.room_number, s.date_in, s.date_out
FROM customers c
    INNER JOIN services s
        ON c.customer_date = s.date_in
WHERE c.customer_date = '$customer_date' ";

$result = @mysql_query($tryshow,$conn)
            or die(mysql_error());    

if (mysql_num_rows($result) == 0) {
    echo "No rows found, nothing to print...";
}
?>
<form> 
<table width="700" border="0">
    <tr>
      <td width="100">Customer Date:</td>
      <td width="100">Last Name</td>
      <td width="100">First Name</td>
      <td width="100">Room Number</td>
      <td width="100">Date In</td>
      <td width="100">Date Out</td>
    </tr>
<?php while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){ ?>
    <tr>
      <td><?php echo $row['customer_date']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row['lastname']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row['firstname']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row['room_number']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row['date_in']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row['date_out']; ?></td>
    </tr>
<?php  }?>
</table>
```

Thanks in advance.

-renz

Comment: It's most likely your data. You probably have services with the same "date in" for the same customers. Just guessing though. The code itself looks fine. Run the query itself on the database and see what you get

Comment: @cfreak your right i run it on phpmyadmin and its the same. what do you think should i do ?

Comment: Fix your data integrity logic

Answer (score 0):

You have two choices, if the query runs the same in phpMyAdmin.  First, you can clean your data.  If this is possible, its the best direction to go.  Better data makes better applications possible.  If you can't do much for the data integrity then you need to account for it.  The simplest way would be to add a distinct to your query....

```
SELECT distinct c.customer_date, c.lastname, c.firstname,
   s.room_number, s.date_in, s.date_out
FROM customers c
    INNER JOIN services s
        ON c.customer_date = s.date_in
WHERE c.customer_date = '$customer_date'
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. i have tried distinct and still the same output.

Comment: Could you post the actual output?

Answer (score 0):

your on clause

```
ON c.customer_date = s.date_in
```

should be on a unique key

```
ON c.room_number = s.room_number
```